# Why was this comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

I've had a comment to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399560/does-the-set-emptyset-emptyset-exist) removed without, well, comment and I'm curious why. The deleted comment was: "(Incidentally, I disagree with the downvote and have upvoted to compensate. Being a duplicate is not the same as being a bad question.)" Is this comment in violation of some policy I'm unaware of?

(This actually happened multiple times, since at first I wasn't sure my comment had in fact gone through.)

Here's a screenshot of the comment thread pre-comment-deletion:

[image]

Comment: Because comments are meant to clarify the question.  Things like "I don't know why this was downvoted [or upvoted]" or "+1!  I've upvoted" or "Thank you!" are considered noise, and are generally deleted.

Comment: Btw,  regarding such so-called "pity upvotes",  see this [prior meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2234/242) for why some users consider them bad for the site.

Comment: Clearly the comment was too big to fit in the margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning Xander Henderson's [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34636/why-was-this-comment-deleted#comment161551_34636) into an answer so it can be voted on:

> Because comments are meant to clarify the question. Things like "I don't know why this was downvoted [or upvoted]" or "+1! I've upvoted" or "Thank you!" are considered noise, and are generally deleted.

Comment: Xander's Comment can be voted up, but not down of course.  Comments on the main site are often described as "ephemeral content" and may be removed once their relevance has waned.

Comment: There are -7 to 7 votes on the answer, so there is some disagreement on the it.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, now -11 to +11.  It is clear that the community is in a state of perfect equanimity.  

Comment: Long time since I laughed so hard at a comment @Lspice

Comment: The pop-up tag for the up(down)vote arrow says "This answer is (not) useful". I deem it to be useful. While I agree that users should be encouraged to upvote rather than make routine positive comments like those cited in the answer, I'm not sure that the noise-reduction benefit of arbitrarily deleting such comments  is worth the friction it causes. In short, I am ambivalent on this issue and positively abstain from voting on it.

Comment: @JohnBentin Typically on meta, the up/down votes indicate agreement/disagreement with the opinion discussed in the post, in contrast to the meaning on the main site. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30104