# Can we limit downvotes without justification to -2

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I can understand why folks downvote and I respect the reasons for doing this.

It seems to me that when a question is at -2 and someone downvotes it further, that this down vote is crossing a line.  Unless there's a legitimate point, this strikes me as just plain mean and aggressive.

This is not an issue that directly affects me as a user.  In my case, I usually delete a question if it gets to -1 so this is not about me.

This is an issue that affects me as a member of the math stack exchange community.  I do not believe an educational community should be unnecessarily harsh or disempowering.

This relates to questions such as this:
[What are the likely fruitful approaches and challenges to be overcome, when tackling this Group cohomology representation of the Collatz conjecture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514670/what-are-the-likely-fruitful-approaches-and-challenges-to-be-overcome-when-tack)

I voted this one up not because I felt terrible that this question had been downvoted to -5.  I am glad that its rating has moved upward.

In my view, the question ideally should really be at 0 if people feel it is not of value and in negative area if there are changes that are expected or if the author could have spent more time before asking the question.

The anonymity of downvotes allows them to be quite cruel.  I understand that there are questions out there that legitimately deserve a lower number than -2 so here's my proposal:

Can we make it that to downvote a question that is already at -2 that we require a justification of a minimum length or a flag of spam or inappropriate content.  If a person doesn't feel strongly enough to provide a justification of mimimum length or a flag, then I suspect that the downvote past -2 is probably inappropriate.

If a question does deserve to go to -3, then let the person who makes the downvote justify it.  When anyone sees a question with -2, they get the point that this is not an authoritative question.

Does this sound reasonable? If I see a -5, I really expect to see spam or someone who asks a question that is completely outrageous.  I don't expect to see a question like the one that I referenced.

Comment: I don't think this is something that can be done per-site, so you should probably ask on the main Meta site.  But I don't see you getting much support, to be honest.  Your choice of $-2$ is arbitrary, which is a problem, but who, exactly, is supposed to assess this "justification of minimum length" and decide if it's good enough?

Comment: I agree. I posted it in case it could be done.  Having a minimal justification is better than the current approach.   I think it makes sense for educational sites such as this.  It may not make sense for other sites on the Meta site.  -2 is arbitrary. I would be open to any minimum threshold chosen. -5 seems too low for this type of question.  That's really my point.

Comment: Can we limit upvotes to +2?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2234/242) for arguments against  "pity upvotes".

Comment: Well, and I think Xander is hinting at this too, a downvote is worth -2 rep and an upvote is worth +10.  So to be "fair", whatever that word should mean in this context, as 5 downvotes equals one upvote that's the ratio that could be looked at to determine a limit.  But equally, if you have to justify downvoting you should have to justify upvoting too.  Sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander, after all.

Comment: @postmortes The "sauce for the goose" is, in my opinion, the more salient point.  Upvoting already swamps downvoting by a fair degree on this site---vanishingly few posts end up with scores lower than $-2$ or $-3$.  People *already* largely limit themselves when it comes to downvoting already heavily downvoted posts.  I don't see a need for this kind of limitation, but *if* such a limitation existed, why make it apply only to downvotes?

Comment: And if such a proposal were adopted, I think it would encourage *hasty* downvotes, as that would allow the downvoter to not have to provide a justification for it.

Comment: Hmmm @XanderHenderson, I find it interesting that you said limit to 2 upvote yet your comment got 3 upvote (just an observation)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Given that the comment was meant to be sardonic, I am not sure why you find that interesting.  Perhaps other simply appreciate my sense of humour?

Comment: @LarryFreeman FYI, regarding requiring comments with downvotes, this issue has been discussed multiple times on the network Meta site, starting from fairly early on, such as at [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521) and [Different implementation of downvoting: require comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66020). ...

Comment: @LarryFreeman (cont.) There's also more recent ones, such as [Feature Request: Require comment for downvotes if user reaches reputation threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327292), which has been closed as a duplicate of $2$ other ones, in particular, [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135) which currently has $31$ non-deleted answers (and $8$ deleted answers). Nonetheless, I don't recall reading any, nor can I find any now, post requesting what you're asking for, i.e., a cut-off point (e.g., your $-2$) for requiring commenting/flagging.

Comment: @LarryFreeman FYI, note there's a good reason, & use, for why some questions should be able to easily go to $-3$. This is since one [trusted users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege is "Voting to delete questions with a score of -$3$ or lower immediately after they are closed". IMHO, this is not needed very often (I've only used it a few times), but there are sometimes posts and/or comments, e.g., ones that contain quite rude and/or abusive content, that should be deleted ASAP, without having to wait hours, or even days, for a diamond moderator to handle.

Comment: Another justification for voting a question below -3 is that questions with a score of -4 or lower gets hidden from the front page. So people may feel that if a PSQ stays on the front page before it could get closed increases the chance of it getting answered, and a downvote is one way of preventing that.

Comment: Did not know that @JohnOmielan.  Any change should take that vote into count.   I think that the downvote to this question shows that folks are strongly against the idea that I proposed.  I still feel it is cruel and disempowering.

Comment: I think that my posing of this question is now at -9 says everything.  I would delete the question if there wasn't an answer since the community has rejected this viewpoint.  @TrystWithFreedom if you delete your answer, I will delete my question.

Comment: It says that I cannot delete this question because people have put too much time into it.  Wow.  I don't see any reason why a question with a -9 should remain?  Even in meta.  Can anyone explain this one to me?

Comment: If this were the main site, the hope is that the negative downvotes would encourage you to improve the question and thus start attracting upvotes.  Despite your views of "cruel and disempowering" the system is intended to empower users to turn things around if they want.  Here on meta, where we view these up- and down-votes as agreement/disagreement, things can still turn around because users are in different timezones.  It's also possible for someone (you/a commentor/an answerer) to make a point that changes everyone's views and the voting (there used to be a badge just for that)

Comment: Why should an opinion be removed because its simply bot the one in majority @larry

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not mind the following , although it looks difficult to implement : let the author only know if the score is $-2$ or below , by indicating it as "$<-1$" or something (even better maybe, just leave it at $0$ if it is actually negative).  Let all visitors vote freely and see the vote count, and let the algorithm use all these votes for its sorting algorithm. I don't know if anyone *other than* the original poster is offended by the downvotes, so ensuring that an OP can't see that number should also be enough. Finally, comments may or may not accompany votes.

Comment: The thinking behind this is that the number of votes being negative affects only the original poster and nobody else *negatively*. The point is, negatively scored posts help guide visitors, so it's impossible to not allow voting at all. Of course , it may also happen (and may already be happening) that users are predisposed towards not downvoting beyond a $-2$ or a $-3$ in general (Note : the question attached to this post had $5$ upvotes prior to this question so it divided opinion , and is an exception to that pattern) and will generally stop at $-2$ or so, unless the question is spam.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer your suggestion doesn't stop the question-poster from seeing the downvotes; they now just have to visit their question anonymously or have a second account to look at it from.  Which they will do, because humans are insatiably curious.  So I suspect your suggestion will create a temptation to create sock-puppet accounts since if you're visiting your question to see it's true votes, you may as upvote yourself with your extra account....

Comment: @postmortes I agree with you, but at the same time express some astonishment at the thought that people will create accounts just to see how many downvotes they've got, only to get put off by the number of downvotes!

Comment: @postmortes to be clear, getting -10 for this question has felt disempowering.  I really regret posting this. I appreciate the points made for how negatives scores are used.   I understand that most folks on this site are accomplished math experts who provide tremendous value for visitors to this site.   I just wish we didn't have to be so negative.  I don't know. If I didn't care about quality, I wouldn't be bothered by -10 response to a meta post.  If I didn't care about this site, I wouldn't have made the post.

Comment: I doubt this will help much but basically: if you stop looking at that score as "I have done something wrong" and start looking at it as "the people who have considered my question seriously don't feel this is the right way to solve it" you might feel better.  And that is what that score is telling you, because that's what it's supposed to do.  Feedback, especially negative feedback, is how people learn and it's really valuable.  You don't have to like it, but since it's built into this site being part of this community means you will have to find a way to live with it.

Comment: Thanks @postmortes I will try to see it that way.

Answer (score -7):

There are few view points one can have on these matters on how we **should** vote. I think they can roughly categorized into two categories which I try to explain here:

#### 1. Quality by Anarchistic voting

[image]

Highlighted points:

1. Emotional indifference to how a question is voted on
2. Quality is what community believes to, so no matter how we vote it's fine./ One desn't need to justify their vote.
3. SE system allows for this naturally.

| Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- |
| Demcoracy Manifest | .....Democracy Manifest? |
| Much less mentally tasking to do as one shouldn't explain their vote | Makes some users feel negative when they receive negative vote |
| Kicks out people who can't conform | Lose potential high value contributors |

##### Some offtopic Remarks:

I think point third row in the table is similar to the real life arguement of natalism vs antinatalism

#### 2.  Principled Voting

[image]

Highlighted points:

1. Different users have different principles. Principles are often based on emotional reasons. I note the main viewpoints I observe ( this is very rough):

   1.1. Some have wish to encourage new users , so they vote positive even if the question is not to the highest quality.

   1.2. Some users vote on presentation on questions. So, for example even if the solution is trivial, they vote to encourage hard work of OP.

   1.3. Vote only if the question has great idea and also presented well
2. Mostly impossible to implement unilaterally a 100%. Different people have different definition of quality. However, what can be done is try to convince others of one's principles by arguements.  What ends up usually happening is, these principled voters come and often try to neutralize the vote of the Anarchist voters to bring a "balance" (this goes both ways, negative and positive voting)

| Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- |
| MSE usage becomes a more fulfilling experience | Giving too much positive feedback may turn quality subpar long term |
| Requires more mental effort to evaluate questions | Less users get triggered |
| MSE becomes more inclusive | Lose current high value contributors because they can't "tolerate" principled posts |

---

#### What's the right way to vote?

I think the issue really derives from people having very different conception on ** the goal of MSE**. If MSE is to become a homework help site (which it already sort of is), then it makes sense to move to some sort of principled voting but if MSE wants to become a museum of the most democratically voted math questions ever, then 1. works.

---

#### Final points:

It could be that this post is total non sense. It is just my personal analysis of the situation but I hope it adds at least a little clarity on the question of "How do people perceive this issue actually?".